# Capturing key events with Griffon

Tags: groovy, griffon

I'm building a Griffon application, and I want to be able to react to key up events so users can easily navigate forward and back with key presses. Are there any examples around that show us how to listen for key events using Griffon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that Griffon always gives you choices, in this case you can drop down one level and register KeyEventListeners on the target component. Another option would to be to use the `keyStrokeAction` node exposed by SwingBuilder, like it's shown by the `slideware` plugin here https://github.com/griffon/griffon-slideware-plugin/blob/master/griffon-app/views/griffon/plugins/slideware/DeckPlayerView.groovy

```
keyStrokeAction(component: deck,
    keyStroke: shortcut('UP'),
    condition: 'in focused window',
    action: lookupAction)
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked well, thanks! I used code of this style successfully:

keyStrokeAction(component: main,
            keyStroke: KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('DOWN'),
            condition: 'in focused window',
            action: prevAction)